# Error "Unable to load the service index for source" while trying to publish a NuGet package to gitlab.com

Tags: gitlab, nuget

I have a private C# project on the [gitlab.com](http://gitlab.com) and want to create a NuGet package there.

I followed the [instruction](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/nuget_repository/#project-level-endpoint-2) and created the following `Nuget.config` file on the solution level.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <packageSources>
 <clear />
 <add key="gitlab" value="https://gitlab.com/api/v4/project/{my_project_numeric_id_here}/packages/nuget/index.json" />
 </packageSources>
 <packageSourceCredentials>
 <gitlab>
     <add key="Username" value="{my_username_in_gitlab}" />
     <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="{my_personal_token_with_api_access_here}" />
 </gitlab>
 </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

Then I used the Visual Studio Package Manager Console and ran the following command:

`dotnet nuget push "C:\{path_to_the_package_here}\MyProject.1.0.0.nupkg" --source gitlab`

and had the following error:

```
error: Unable to load the service index for source https://gitlab.com/api/v4/project/{my_project_numeric_id_here}/packages/nuget/index.json.
error: Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
```

`MyProject.1.0.0.nupkg` — exists.

`Nuget.config` — is seen by the command (reflects changes in the file).

`Personal Token` — I played with different permissions, at least api permission is granted, and all others too.

What is wrong in my actions and how to create a NuGet package from the C# project on GitLab.com?

Comment: Is it possible that project id `{my_project_numeric_id_here}` does not exists?

Comment: I have the same issue and I am sorry to see that you did not indicate the solution...

Comment: What was the solution? I ma having same issue.